# Computing statistical results for the test dataset in PyTorch - Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, static-analysis

I'm creating a vanilla neural network with artificial datasets to learn `pytorch`. I'm currently looking how I can get the predictions for the test data set and obtain the statistical metrics including `mse`, `mae`, and `r2`. I was wondering if my calculations are correct. Also, is there any built-in function that could potentially give me all these results in `pytorch` as it happens in `sckit-learn`?

Let's first upload libraries and then generate artificial training and test data.

```
import random
import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset,DataLoader,TensorDataset
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import math


n_input, n_hidden, n_out= 5, 64, 1

#Create training and test datasets
X_train =  pd.DataFrame([[random.random() for i in range(n_input)] for j in range(1000)])
y_train =  pd.DataFrame([[random.random() for i in range(n_out)] for j in range(1000)])

X_test =  pd.DataFrame([[random.random() for i in range(n_input)] for j in range(50)])
y_test  =  pd.DataFrame([[random.random() for i in range(n_out)] for j in range(50)])



test_dataset = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(X_test.to_numpy().astype(np.float32)), torch.Tensor((y_test).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)))
testloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size= 32)

#For training, use 32 as a batch size
training_dataset = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(X_train.to_numpy().astype(np.float32)), torch.Tensor((y_train).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)))
dataloader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Now, let us generate the model to train.

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_input, n_hidden),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_out),
                      nn.ReLU())
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Next, I start the training process.

```
losses = []
epochs = 1000

for epoch in range(epochs+1): 
    for times,(x_train,y_train) in enumerate(dataloader):
        y_pred  = model(x_train) 
        loss = loss_function(y_pred, y_train) 
   
        model.zero_grad() 
        loss.backward() 

        optimizer.step()
```

Now, I'd like to get the predictions for the test dataset and get statistical results. This is the part that I need help and some guidance.  Do they seem correct? Is there something I might be doing wrong?

```
from torchmetrics import R2Score

r2score = R2Score()
running_mae = running_mse = running_r2 = 0

with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    for times,(x_test,y_test) in enumerate(testloader):
        y_pred = model(x_test)
        error = torch.abs(y_pred - y_test).sum().data
        squared_error=((y_pred - y_test)*(y_pred - y_test)).sum().data
        running_mae+=error
        running_mse+=squared_error
        running_r2+=r2score(y_pred, y_test)
mse =  math.sqrt(squared_error/ len(testloader))
mae = error / len(testloader)
r2 = running_r2 / len(testloader)
print("MSE:",mse, "MAE:", mae, "R2:", r2)
```